# Discover an event isn't the first instance, and that isn't good

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, expressions

I'm looking for a word or phrase, preferably English or at least using English characters, to describe an event or feeling about an event that is one of many, but that the person thought was the first or original.

For instance, Odysseus' journey is an epic. But then we discover proof that he (and others) actually made that trip many times, and that that journey was nothing special. To the age, this was as harrowing as a 6 hour flight to us.

Disappointing to say the least, but I'm looking for a word or phrase that really captures that "let down" feeling.

So instead of Odysseus' journey being an epic, now it's Odysseus' *<word or phrase>* journey. Or maybe Odysseus' journey of *<word or phrase>*.

But as an event, so while "commute" works for my example, it doesn't work for many non-travel events. Other example may have been finding an ancient nuclear reactor, so that not special anymore. Or discovering Old Faithful isn't just a one time thing, but very routine. Or finding microbial life (or greater) on every single planetoid we search.

I'm really hoping to capture that feeling, that let down, from the unique and special, to the mundane. But as a stroke victim my vocabulary escapes me.

Comment: Such a shock would *burst my bubble* and have me *crestfallen*.

Comment: It might be a disappointment to discover that your epiphany was actually a routine experience, but rewarding to realise you aren't out on a limb.

Comment: The event is often called a knowledge bomb. https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22knowledge+bomb%22&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS1086US1087&oq=define+%22knowledge+bomb%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigATIHCAMQIRigATIHCAQQIRigATIHCAUQIRigATIHCAYQIRirAjIHCAcQIRirAjIHCAgQIRirAtIBCTEyNTkxajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . As to it's effect - that's up to you.

Comment: Then Odysseus' journey was just a *Milk Run*. Remembered distantly but fondly by those of us who remember milk being delivered from house to house.

Comment: I found a mere 1-hour flight in a 12-seater airplane over Indiana cornfields during a thunderstorm quite harrowing. That said, you can supplant the awesomeness of almost anything with snark and cynicism by replacing the original noun phrase:  Armstrong's big whoop for all mankind. We took a road trip to see that big whoop in Yellowstone.

Comment: @Elliot Milk run doesn't generalize to other types of events.

Comment: "epic" doesn't have anything to do with being unique. It means a long work of art about heroic deeds and adventures. Even if long journeys were routine, they didn't usually involve all the dangers that Odysseus encountered and overcame.

Comment: Would the verb *to cheapen* work? Of course that's a word for the phenomenon, so to speak, not the feeling resulting from it.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to discover something and learn that it had previously been discovered, I would be finding out that I was ***beat to the punch***. If the person who completed the task before me took credit that I was expecting to get, they would have ***stolen my thunder***.

I think this works more for things that you are doing or encountering first, but where you find the **tracks are well-tread**, that the **trail has been blazed** or that the **routes have been set**. It doesn't work for things that start out novel and exciting and become more rote.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but you may want to double-check the tense in some of your expressions.